# Calculate some integrals involving Jacobi Elliptic Functions

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals, elliptic-integrals, elliptic-functions

I want evaluate the follow integrals
$$\displaystyle \int_{0}^{K} \text{dn}^3(u;k)\text{sn}(u;k)^2\;\text{du},\tag{1}$$
and
$$\displaystyle \int_{0}^{K} \text{dn}(u;k)\text{sn}(u;k)^2\text{cn}(u;k)^2\;\text{du},\tag{2}$$
where $\text{sn}$, $\text{dn}$ and $\text{cn}$ are the Jacobi Elliptic *snoidal*, *dnoidal* and *cnoidal* functions, $K:=K(k)$ is the complete elliptic integral of the first kind and number $k \in \left(0,1\right)$ is called the modulus.

I already consulted the reference $[1]$ in search of some formula that helps me, but I found nothing. Do these integrals have an explicit form? Are there any other references I can refer to to help me?

[$[1]$](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=Cr_3CAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&hl=pt-BR&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false) P. F. Byrd. M. D. Friedman. Hand Book of Elliptical Integrals for Engineers and Scientis. Springer-Verlag New York Heidelberg Berlim, $1971$.

Comment: Mathematica V12.1 gives (4-3k^2)Pi/16 for (1) and Pi/16 for (2).

Comment: @Somos Is it possible to do this on Maple?

Comment: And if the integrals are valued from $ 0 $ to $ 4K (k) $?

Comment: As for Mathematica, try it yourself at [WolframCloud](https://develop.open.wolframcloud.com/view/newNotebook). I think it should be possible with Maple but I don't have Maple.

Comment: @Somos I calculated [here](https://develop.wolframcloud.com/env/c2895203-84c1-49e3-8576-ef2c358746b9). And it is according to what you originally said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By means of the fundamental relations (B&F 121.00) $\newcommand{sn}{\operatorname{sn}}\newcommand{cn}{\operatorname{cn}}\newcommand{dn}{\operatorname{dn}}$
$$\sn^2u+\cn^2u=1$$
$$k^2\sn^2u+\dn^2u=1$$
we can transform the first given integral to
$$\int_0^K\dn u(1-k^2\sn^2u)\sn^2u\,du$$
By B&F 364.03 we can rewrite this as a completely rational integral, which is easily evaluated:
$$=2\int_0^1\left(\left(\frac{2t}{1+t^2}\right)^2-k^2\left(\frac{2t}{1+t^2}\right)^4\right)\frac1{1+t^2}\,dt=\frac{\pi(4-3k^2)}{16}$$
When we transform the second given integral we get
$$\int_0^K\dn u(1-\sn^2u)\sn^2u\,du$$
at which point we realise that this is just a special case of the first given integral with $k^2=1$, so we immediately get the result as $\frac\pi{16}$.